# How to remove child component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-mapbox-gl

I am using react native mapbox and have several and dynamic child component(layers) in Map component.

Something like:

```
<MapboxGL.MapView ...>
   <MapboxGL.RasterSource>
   ...
   </MapboxGL.RasterSource>
  ...
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

There so many child component dynamic and conditonal.

I want to remove unwanted component because update some component doest not support.

So any suggestion or idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use state and conditionally render your items depending on the state e.g

```
const Component = ()=>{
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return (
    <MapboxGL.MapView ...>
      {...}
      // you can shortcircuit here
      {isVisible && <DynamicComponent>}
      // this should also work
      {isVisible ? <AnotherComponent/> : null }
    </MapboxGL.MapView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. is there any way to remove a child componet without condition?

Comment: At the top of my head there is nothing I am aware of, if you can provide the usecase then maybe maybe I can try and figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
const Component = ()=>{
  const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MapboxGL.MapView ...> 
      
      {showComponent && (
          <View>{.....}</View>
          : null }
      
    </MapboxGL.MapView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).